# protractor hangs after running a .sendKeys

Tags: async-await, protractor, sendkeys

I am new to using protractor and am struggling with getting even a simple script running.

The symptom is "field1" is populated and then the script hangs. Removing the "await" on the .sendKeys causes the script to run but if I then move "if (await field2.isPresent()) {" down to below the "field1" sendKeys then once again only the "field1" is populated.

The issue seems to me to be around promises, but only a guess. What I need is to be able to have my .isPresent checks anywhere in my scripts. This is obviously a simplified example and is done for ease of explanation.

angular version 6

## protractor.conf.js

allScriptsTimeout: 30000,
...
SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false,

## package.json extract

"cucumber": "^5.0.2",
"cucumber-html-reporter": "^4.0.4",
"jasmine": "^3.3.0",
"jasmine-core": "2.99.1",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1",
"protractor": "^5.4.1",
"protractor-cucumber-framework": "^6.1.1",
"protractor-html-screenshot-reporter": "0.0.21",

```
Given ('peek capture is running', {timeout: 30000},  async function ()  {
    await browser.get('#/login');
    let field1: ElementFinder = element(by.id('login-email'));
    let field2: ElementFinder = element(by.id('login-password'));
    let field3: ElementFinder = element(by.css('#theButton'));
    if (await field1.isPresent()) {
        if (await field2.isPresent()) {
            await field1.sendKeys('theuser@the.org');
            await field2.sendKeys('the password');
            await field3.click();

            await browser.sleep(1500);
        }
    }
    return(null);
});
```

Comment: First of all, do you use `if (.isPresent())` twice to make sure that the page is loaded? And second, somehow protractor doesn't work on my login page as it was non angular (even though it is angular indeed). So I had to `await browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);` before openning the page and `await browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);` after I logged in. But I was getting errors specific to this problem. So try second option, if doesn't help, answer first question and we'll go from there

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of ExpectedConditions in protractor

https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions

```
Given ('peek capture is running', {timeout: 30000},  async function ()  {

var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var input1 = element(by.id('login-email'));
var input2 = element(by.id('login-password'));
var btn = element(by.css('#theButton'));
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(input1), 10000);
input1.sendKeys('****');
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(input2), 10000);
input2.sendKeys('****');
browser.wait(EC.isClickable(btn), 10000);
btn.click();

})
```

Comment: If I use "browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(field),10000);" then the code does not stop, however looking at browser.wait I see it is returning a promise so I need an "await" on the browser.wait. If I do the problem returns and the script times out, if I do not use a await on the browser.wait then the script just runs straight through the line with no wait for the element.

Comment: Did you add await keyword before browser.wait?

Comment: Yes, if I did not then browser.wait does not wait. As I understand it if I set SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false, then I handle promises, and as I am using new promises I used await. Am I wrong?